# Price display on node-product .tpl

Tags: commerce

I have one product with 5 variations

book:
paperback, hard cover; audio; ebook(epub, mobi)

How do i display the individual prices per item on node

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `Product Referenced` field hanged on your content type you can access your `Product ID` in content 's `$product_id = $vars['node']['field_product']` then you can get commerce product item with `commerce_product_load($product_id)` and then access `field_price`.